# How to remove all default Anchor styles so element is unaffected?

Tags: html, css

Is there a set of styles that you can set to remove all anchor styles?

The most I can do is remove the text decoration but I don't want to define a color because each text field could be a different color:

```css
#text {
    color: green;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="" id="text">
    Text
</a>
```

**UPDATE:**

There was a typo in my code. So the link was not connected to the style rule.

Comment: This question is so confusing

Comment: My anchors are blue and underlined.

Comment: There was a typo in my code. So the link was not connected to the style rule.

Comment: You want to target an element and say this element should ignore all styles applied to it ?

Comment: No there was a typo in my code. So my text had turned blue and underlined. It's fine now

Answer (score 3):

```
a { color: inherit; }
```

… will cause the element to take on the colour of its parent (which is what I think you are looking for).
explanation of [inherit](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inherit) property

Answer (score 1):

```css
a {

    text-decoration: none;
    color: unset; 
}

/* Global values */
color: inherit;
color: initial;
color: unset;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/color

use `unset` instead of `none`